# Google tag manager data layer within iframes

Tags: iframe, google-tag-manager

I am no sure how to setup the dataLayer across iframes with the Google tag manager.
I found the following information:
[Google Tag Manager dataLayer within iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382182/google-tag-manager-datalayer-within-iFrames)

On the website is the iFrame. The iFrame is loaded on an sudomain.

> Parentpage: www.domain.com
>
> iFrame: www.sudomain.domain.com

Is it correct to setup the GTM container on the parentpage and define all dataLayer variable there and push the dataLayer from the iFrame via the `parent.dataLayer.push` method?

Does the `parent.dataLayer.push` method then push the dataLayer values automatically to the dataLayer on the parentpage?

For example:

Parentpage

```
dataLayer = [{
        'country': 'DE',
        'pageType': 'product'
    }]
```

Then the iFrame will be loaded with the `parent.dataLayer.push` method:

```
parent.dataLayer.push({
        'country': 'DE',
        'pageType': 'product123'    });
```

Will the dataLayer value for 'pageType' in the parentpage then automatically be overwritten by the iframe value)?

Thanks